# Equivalent description of Lp norm

Tags: functional-analysis, real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space with measure $\mu$, $\mu(X)>0 $, let $f$ be an arbitrary measurable complex function. I want to show that regardless of whether $f \in L^p(X)$  ($1 \leq p \leq \infty$) or not, we have
$$\|f\|_p=\sup \left\{\left|\int_{X} f\phi d\mu \right| , \phi \text{  is simple, and }\|\phi \|_q \leq 1\right\}$$
I am confused about the situation where $\|f\|_p=\infty$, how can we find such $\phi$ to make $ \left|\int_{X} f\phi d\mu \right| $ sufficiently large.

Comment: Reduce to the case $f\ge0$ and then approximate $f$ with a sequence of simple functions $0\le \phi_j\uparrow f$ almost everywhere

Comment: @PieroD'Ancona Thanks! Good idea!